# ComponentDidUpdate - Maximum update depth exceeded - Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a slider and every time I click on one slide I want to get the current active index. Based on the current index I want to set the state, but I keep getting `Maximum update depth exceeded`.

```
state = {
    profiles: profileData,
    educations: educationData,
    selectedProfile: localStorage.getItem('slug'),
    selectedEducation: localStorage.getItem('sector') || '',
    popupActive: false,
    profileSelected: true,
    sector: 'Zorg',
    showVideo: true,
    primaryImg: Timmerman,
    redirect: false,
    defaultImage: Default,
    noSector: Tijdelijk,
    slideActive: true,
    playState: false,
    primaryVid:
        'https://localhost.web/videos/desktop/fase2/NPRZ_ADB_Video_2_1_V2.mp4',
    thumbIndex: 0,
    showTumbs: false,
};


componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.slideActive === true) {
        console.log('Thumbs showing');
        this.setState({
            slideActive: false,
        });
    }
}

// Switch the primary splashscreen and vid src with the image clicked
switchPrimary = e => {
    this.setState({
        primaryImg: e.target.style.backgroundImage.split(/"/)[1], // get the data so that it can be passed on to the child component
        primaryVid: e.target.getAttribute('data'), // get the data so that it can be passed on to the child component
        slideActive: true,
        thumbIndex: e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-index'),
        playFromThumb: true,
        showTumbs: false,
    });

    // console.log('hiding:', this.state.showTumbs);

    // console.log('actief');

    // if (this.state.showTumbs === false) {
    //     this.setState({
    //         showTumbs: true,
    //     });
    // }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking if `slideActive` in state is true in `componentDidUpdate`, and if it is you call `setState`, which will result in a new call to `componentDidUpdate`, and the loop continues.

You also want to check that `slideActive` actually changed from the previous update.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.slideActive !== this.state.slideActive && this.state.slideActive) {
    console.log("Thumbs showing");
    this.setState({
      slideActive: false
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put you logic inside `componentDidMount` inside a condition comparing old state to new or old vs new props to avoid it:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition, or you’ll cause an infinite loop.

more read and examples: [React ComponentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)